# Where to find localhost files with Apache?

Tags: apache, windows-7, localhost

I recently installed Apache and enabled "localhost" with Windows.  When I type "localhost" in my browser, it brings me to a page explaining that the Apache installation was successful.  I just don't know where to find this.  Is it reading some index.html file?  If so, I just can't find it.

I tried going to C:\inetpub\wwwroot but the "localhost" in the browser is not reading it from this location.  Where else is it reading localhost from?  I use Windows 7.

Comment: Is anyone able to help with this?  I'm not sure where else to go with this question.  Thanks!

Comment: There should be a file with the path as a parameter, I´ve been trying with httpd.conf but not luck, Localhost is showing the index file from anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually found in `\apache\htdocs` on a Windows default install. The 'Pre-Installation' steps covered in this [Apache, PHP and MySQL setup guide](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/how-to-setup-local-web-server-with-latest-apache-php-and-mysql-packages/) might be helpful.

If you use a default install of [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), it will be in `C:\wamp\www`